# Removing the space above the searchable search bar in navigation view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am testing out the SwiftUI's feature .searchable(). But seems that the search bar would always has a space above it. Since the searchable is embedded in the naviagation bar, I understand the space as where the Navigation bar items go. But is there a way to remove that space and make the searchbar looking like that in Instagram? I have tried changing the navbar style to inline,as the code below, but there is still some space above it. Is there any logic behind the search bar's position?

```
NavigationView{
    SearchView(searchText: $searchText)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) 
}
.searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), suggestions: {
    ForEach(searchResults, id: \.self){result in
        Text(result).searchCompletion(result)
        
    }
})
```

[The Space Marked with Brown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9qRS.png)

Comment: try: `.navigationBarHidden(true)`

Comment: just tried, the whole bar would be gone.

Comment: try to add inside the SearchView itself (not the searchView inside the navigationView). navigationTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) ,

Comment: the search bar was also gone in this way. but the thing is, if the searchable bar is a part of the navigation view's navigation bar section, hiding the navigation bar should be affecting the search in it, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I just found a way to remove it. The way to remove the space above the search bar is to avoid using the built-in .searchable modifier, and instead use the UIKit's UISearchBar by creating a UIViewRepresentable SwiftUI view. This gives you full control over the appearance and behavior of the search bar. Here's an example of how to do this:

First, create the SearchBar struct:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholder: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.placeholder = placeholder
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        return searchBar
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }
        
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            text = searchText
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use SearchBar in your SwiftUI views like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SearchBar(text: $searchText, placeholder: "Search")
            // Your other views here...
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you a search bar at the very top of your SwiftUI view.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to get a search bar in a `SwiftUI` view while using `UIKit` navigation. I had no luck with `searchable` either... This does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but what worked for me is adding `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`

I think the issue is that the `NavigationView` defaults to a large display mode.